# How to integrate cypress-mochawesome-reporter to Gitlab pages?

Tags: cypress, cicd, mochawesome

How to integrate cypress-mochawesome-reporter to Gitlab pages?

Currently i have this code on my gitci-.yml

```
stages: 
  - test

test:
  image: cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run start:ci &
    - npm run html-report
```

The cypress-mochawesome-reporter produce an **index.html** inside **cypress/reports/html/index.html** file after the pipeline runs

I can't find any docs or tutorial in the internet. What is the best approach on this?